# Using React Redux, when click the link on the side bar (to redirect) to clear the input in the search bar at the same time

Tags: reactjs, search, react-redux

I'm using react redux to create a website. I have a header component which includes the search bar and I put it on in the App.jsx so that every page can get this header. But now the problem is that when I click the link on the side bar of some other component to redirect, how could I clear the input in the search bar at the same time? since my header is separate from the other component but the search bar is inside the header component so I wonder if there is a way to connect back to the search bar in the header component. So that when I click the link of the other component I can reset the input of the search bar to be empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the search you can check whether the location is same or different :

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

        if (get(this.props, 'location.pathname') !== get(prevProps, 'location.pathname')) {
          //clear search 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a search bar state in redux which will control the content of the search bar.